# When I have micro cuts in the network wifi is not reconnected

Tags: networking, drivers, asus, iwlwifi, rtl8723be

I have an ASUS ROG GL553V, recently I've installed Ubuntu 16.04, with gnome desktop. I had problems with the wifi card, and I tried lots of solutions that I found including [this](https://blog.desdelinux.net/realtek-rtl8723be-ubuntu-derivados/) and [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=204172&hilit=Rtl8723be&start=80#p1286298) without success.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlp2s0
       versión: 00
       serie: f8:28:19:0c:6c:c2
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-041500-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memoria:df300000-df303fff
  *-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nombre lógico: enp3s0
       versión: 15
       serie: 10:7b:44:2e:10:be
       tamaño: 10Mbit/s
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:125 ioport:c000(size=256) memoria:df204000-df204fff memoria:df200000-df203fff
```

Don't know what else can I do.

EDIT 1:

My `lsmod` output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  2
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  2
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_netlink    40960  0
nfnetlink              16384  2 nf_conntrack_netlink
xfrm_user              32768  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  5
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
xt_addrtype            16384  2
iptable_filter         16384  1
ip_tables              28672  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
xt_conntrack           16384  2
x_tables               40960  5 ip_tables,iptable_filter,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_addrtype,xt_conntrack
nf_nat                 32768  2 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4
nf_conntrack          131072  7 nf_conntrack_ipv4,ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
br_netfilter           24576  0
bridge                151552  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
overlay                77824  0
ccm                    20480  3
bbswitch               16384  0
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
bnep                   20480  2
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               471040  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
hid_multitouch         20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
intel_rapl             20480  0
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  31 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
uvcvideo               86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
joydev                 20480  0
kvm_intel             204800  0
snd_usb_audio         196608  4
snd_usbmidi_lib        32768  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  6
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
arc4                   16384  2
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
rtl8723be              98304  0
pcbc                   16384  0
btcoexist             131072  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8723be
aesni_intel           188416  2
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm                98304  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
rtlwifi                77824  4 rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8723_common,rtl8723be
mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cfg80211              622592  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd_rawmidi            32768  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
nvidia_uvm            667648  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  33 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
input_leds             16384  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
mei_me                 40960  0
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
idma64                 20480  0
virt_dma               16384  1 idma64
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi
tpm_crb                16384  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
asus_wireless          16384  0
acpi_pad              180224  0
coretemp               16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
autofs4                40960  2
hid_asus               20480  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
i915                 1605632  4
nvidia_drm             20480  6
nvidia_modeset        860160  6 nvidia_drm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 i915
nvidia              13139968  444 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   397312  8 i915,nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
ahci                   36864  4
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
mii                    16384  1 r8169
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  5 i2c_hid,hid_asus,hid_generic,usbhid,hid_multitouch
video                  40960  1 i915
```

EDIT 2:

If I run `lsmod` to view what modules are installed I get this:

```
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  4 rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8723_common,rtl8723be
mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              622592  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

And don't know if that is ok, and when the OS strat it gave me an error with `rtlwifi-new-dkms`. The crash report is:

```
mié feb 28 08:55:16 -03 2018 crash report /var/crash/rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash detected
/var/crash/rtlwifi-new-dkms
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
mié feb 28 08:58:21 -03 2018 crash report /var/crash/rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash detected
```

Comment: Seems like the `rtlwifi` module is crashing. That would be a bug report more than a support question. However, you're using a two-year-old Ubuntu. Before filing a bug report, try reproducing the problem in a 17.10 LiveUSB - the bug may have been fixed in the past couple years.

Comment: But 17.10 soon will not recive more support. I used the version 16.04.3 becouse is LTS.

Comment: I **didn't** say to replace your system with 17.10. Try a LiveUSB specifically because it won't touch your existing system.

Comment: No I know you did not say to replace, I want to replace for one that not have issues with that module. I need to be up and running

Comment: Try out 17.10 and if it's a kernel issue we can give you a newer kernel on 16.04.  If it's not we'll have to dig in deeper, but that's going to take time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I had solved the issue changing to Debian 9, with this version my laptop behavior it's stable.

With Ubuntu 16.04 I had updated the kernel, but that not solve nothing to me. So I decided to change to Debian. Now all works fine.